# Ruby HTML Scrape runs Nil:Nil Class on instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

Within this Scrape implementation the 'results' instance_variable array run a nil nil Class in the html views.. Why was the data not traveling? This Only happened in an Ruby on Rails implement & did indeed work as a Terminal exercise.(returning an abundant array of page elements)

Lets jump into the code.

```
#hiddenmovies initalizer for featured
class Entry
    def intiialize(title, link)
        @title = title
        @link = link
        # @img = img
    end
    attr_accessor :title, :link
end

def featured
    #hiddenmovies scrape
    tag_selector = "script"
    base_selector = ".item"
    css_selector_1 = "img"
    css_selector_2 = "a"
    css_selector_3 = "img"
    begin
        Timeout.timeout(10) do # Opening timeOut block.

            url_test = "http://hiddenmovies.xyz"
            response = HTTParty.get(url_test)

            doc = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, driver_path: '/Users/Michaels/.phantomjs/2.1.1/darwin/bin/phantomjs' #(For development env)

            @hiddenmovies = response

            if response != ''
                if response.code == 200

                    url = "http://hiddenmovies.xyz"

                    doc.get(url)
                    doc.switch_to.default_content
                    doc.find_elements(:css, tag_selector).remove

                    entries = doc.find_elements(:css, base_selector) #fetch_array of elements


                    @results = []
                    if entries != 0
                        entries.each do | entry |
                            title = entry.find_element(:css, css_selector_1).attribute(:alt)  #get_titles
                            link = entry.find_element(:css, css_selector_2).attribute(:href)  #get_item_links
                            img_url = entry.find_element(:css, css_selector_3).attribute(:src)    #get_img_links
                            prep_url = "<img src="
                            apend_url = ">"
                            img = prep_url << img_url << apend_url
                            @results << Entry.new(title, link)
                        end
                    else
                        @no_result = "No results found" 
                    end 
                else
                    @failure_1 = "Hiddenmovies has run a bad request.."
                end
            else
                @failure_2 = "Hiddenmovies run a 404 response."
            end
        end # end timout block
    rescue Timeout::Error
        @timed_out = "Request timed out. Try reload page soon."
    end
end
```

Over in the views we are just iterating the results instance variable in a simple bootstrap table - which did return a nil Class error - So why was the array apparently empty?

The site in the code example is currently 'down' but it was 'up' when this code base was written. I am just curious as to why it did not work?